# Implementation Searchview in snapping recycleview with snaphelper

Tags: android

i am using recycleview with snapHelper following the example using https://github.com/rubensousa/RecyclerViewSnap/

how to implement search View in the recycleview for searching the list.

Comment: Yo can filter your adapter

Comment: how to use filter since we have two adapter for the recycleview. Using filter for second adapter will give "null object reference error".

Comment: SnapAdapter  is just gravity adapter   ..i never tried but it can be possible from the other adapter in demo of library name of it "new Adapter()"  hope it can be help

Comment: I have tried to implement in another adapter but it seems to give null object reference error.

Comment: I have implemented search like this.
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
       if (filter == null){
           filter = new SearchFilter(this,productsList);
       }
       return filter;
    }

Comment: try it http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/05/13/filtering-a-recyclerview-with-custom-objects/

Comment: Using following method from the link does not give any response. Search method is also not working.

Comment: now only way show me your code

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sawrose15/13840f4ca4c054242d9da548a5146419 this is the code..

Comment: Still SearchFilter  class remaining   thats main thing

Comment: I think there is no problem in search class since i have used that class before in another aplication.